# What is advantage of Local Storage over Cookie with Security perspective?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I need to store important oauth grant tokens which should be tamper proof.

Which one is more secure traditional cookies or HTML5 local storage?

Comment: *Whom* are you trying to protect those tokens from…?!

Comment: I am trying to protect these tokens from security vulnerability attacks.

Comment: Like what for example…? Men-in-the-middle? Malware on the PC? The user themselves? *"Make it so my code can't be hacked"* is too vague, broad and practically speaking unrealistic for *all* imaginable threats.

Comment: Yeah true. I want to refer Man in the middle attack here. Someone can copy these to manipulate requests further to inject malicious intrusion in request!

Comment: So you're worried about transmission over the wire. For that purpose it's pretty irrelevant how the values are stored at rest, they'll look identical on the wire. (Cookies are sent more often, as Marco explains below, but *when* they're sent they're equal for all intents and purposes.) To protect transmission of secrets over the wire use HTTPS, then this is a rather moot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is tamper proof—at least, never assume it is.

One key difference between cookies and localStorage is that, cookies on any given domain will automatically get sent back to the server-side on each request to the given domain. This means your oauth token would be sent to the server whether or not the server-side needs it. Keeping the token in localStorage, you'll have to add some JS code to explicitly/manually dig it out from localStorage before you can send it to the server.